# Duration of each candlestick in UNIX

Tags: pine-script

How can we calculate the duration of each candle (not Session) in UNIX?
For example, 86400000 for daily time frame.

I used the following code and it works well for the crypto currency market which is active 24 hours a day and seven days a week, but in the stock market it returns the session time:

```
interval := na(interval) ? time_close - time : interval
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate this on every bar. You could just use this:

```
var int interval = time_close - time
```

It works in both crypto and stock markets, and returns the duration of a bar (in milliseconds) for the current timeframe.

**Edit 1**

This will work better I think

```
var float interval = na

if bar_index == 1
    interval := time - time[1]
```

**Edit 2**

```
//@version=4
study("Time Offset Calculation Framework - PineCoders FAQ", "", true, max_lines_count = 10)

// ———————————————————— Functions.
// ————— Converts current chart resolution into a float minutes value.
f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

var float resInMinutes        = f_resInMinutes()
var float resInSeconds        = resInMinutes * 60
var float resInMilliSeconds   = resInSeconds * 1000

// Plot chart interval in minutes in Data Window.
plotchar(resInMinutes,      "resInMinutes",      "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(resInSeconds,      "resInSeconds",      "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(resInMilliSeconds, "resInMilliSeconds", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Source: [Time Offset Calculation Framework - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/5mZ7hV66-Time-Offset-Calculation-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/)

Comment: I've added Edit 1 section to my answer. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: If you run this code for BITSTAMP: BTCUSD, it will show 86,400,000, which is the length of a day in milliseconds.
But for NSE: BANKNIFTY shows 22,500,000.
In fact, both display the session duration.
But I want the timeframe interval in unix format.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect for `NSE:BANKNIFTY`? Please also mention the timeframe you expect the result on.

Comment: This code can not be calculated in the first candlestick (index = 0) and also the market may be closed on holidays and the time interval between candlesticks will be longer and show a larger interval value.

Comment: I want to show the duration of each time frame in milliseconds. For example, 60.000 for one minute time frame, 3.600.000 for one hour time frame and 86.400.000 for one day time frame.

Comment: Added Edit 2 section to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
The second edit was correct, and very accurate
Especially 30.4375
;)